# Generating type declaration from import url using the TypeScript compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm trying to generate some type declarations for a project.
The main idea here is that I got to a point where I am able to generate something like this:

```js
type T = typeof import("somepath").default
```

Where `default` is a function.

The code that does this is:

```js
ts.createTypeAliasDeclaration(
  undefined,
  undefined,
  ts.createIdentifier("T"),
  undefined,
  ts.createTypeOf(
    ts.createPropertyAccess(
      ts.createCall(
        ts.createToken(ts.SyntaxKind.ImportKeyword),
        undefined,
        [ts.createStringLiteral("somepath")]
      ), 
      ts.createIdentifier("default"))
    ),
    undefined,
    true
);
```

After printing that to the console I can see the output of that is indeed:

```js
type T = typeof import("somepath").default
```

Now I have a variable, say `t` that holds the node of that type alias declaration, but when I try to extract the type with the type checker I keep getting `any`.
So far I've tried `checker.getTypeAtLocation` and `checker.getTypeFromTypeNode` but I keep getting `any` no matter what I try (I checked manually and vscode can indeed verify the type is not `any`).

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler was designed to do type checking before transformation and so for the most part the type checker assumes the node it's type checking will be contained in a source file node and that the source file's text will match the descendant AST nodes (there's some internal data that gets set on nodes when parsing text to a source file).

You can make this work by printing out the node to text (using `ts.createPrinter`), reparsing it in a source file (`ts.createSourceFile`... or updating an existing source file with the `update` method), getting a reference to the parsed `T` type alias node, then using that source file in a new program to get a new type checker. It's a lot of code, so it would be too much work to post it here.

Comment: I see, I was hoping to avoid creating another source file and reparsing but it seems there's no other way.
Thanks!

Comment: hey david, can take a look at this question also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056834/react-types-default-to-any-when-encountering-them-with-the-typescript-compiler