# React types default to `any` when encountering them with the TypeScript compiler API's type checker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm trying to extract some type information from a .d.ts file containing some `typeof import`s here's a sample:

```
type A = {
  someFunc: typeof import('path-to-function').default,
  someComponent: typeof import('path-to-component').MyComponent
};
```

When I extract the types of these `typeof import` statements, the regular function's type is displayed correctly but the component's type is defaulted to `any`.
However, when I hover over the component inside the file the editor extracts the full type (eg. `React.FC<Props>`...).

Is there a way to extract React's types as well using the type checker? I tried playing with the compiler options with `ts.createProgram` but I couldn't overcome this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any diagnostics when calling `ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)`?

Comment: @DavidSherret omg! was missing `esModuleInterop`! Thanks a lot! you're a savior!!!